¿Por que la ejecucion de mi proyecto SSIS en SQL Server no pasa de la validación de flujo de datos?
Tengo un flujo de datos desarrollado en SSIS, si le doy ejecutar desde Visual Studio funciona sin problemas, pero cuando le doy ejecutar desde SQL Server de forma manual no termina la ejecución y no termina el paso de validación de Data Flow Task.
¿Por favor podrían ayudarme a descifrar el motivo por el cual no termina la ejecución?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
